# Join two bezier curves so that the result is two-times continuously differentiable

Tags: graphics, bezier

I have a task to join two bezier curves, so that the resulting curve is two-times continuously differentiable.
I have the cubic bezier Curve C with control points:
c0 = (1,1)
c1 = (3,4)
c2 = (7,5)
c3 = (8,2)
I shall continue this curve C with Curve D from control point c3 to a control point d3 = (12,1) so that this curve is two-times continuously differentiable.
First Task: Determine control points d0, d1, d1 for the new curve.
Second Task: Specify a pecewise defined formula for the new curve G(v) with v out of [0,1] that passes through c0,c3 and d3. Thus connect curves C and D in v = 1/2.
Third Task: Prove by calculation that the transition between C and D is two-times continuously differentiable.
Regarding first task: I don't know how to determine the points. Can someone help to do this? The rest of the tasks is then maybe something easier to do for me. Tank You!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming.

Comment: I'm fine with your oppinion, but that does not help me. Thanks for participation.

Comment: @DeDo it might not help you but ["what can I ask about on Stackoverflow"](/help/on-topic) and ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) exist for you to understand why your question might get voted closed. This is way more of a https://math.stackexchange.com/ question, and so should really be asked there. I don't see any code, so it's not a programming question (yet), and does not fit into this particular stack exchange site as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Basically think about "knots" and "handles" instead of cubic Bezier sections. The knot points, points on the spline, have an "in" point and an "out point". The point always has G0 continuity - end of the first section equal start of the second section. For G1 continuity - no corner - make sure that the handles and knot point form a straight line, and are not degenerate, i.e. of zero length. For G2 continuity - curvature continuity - make sure that the handles are both of the same length, as well as being on a  straight line. Again, exclude degenerates.

Answer (score 0):

For cubic Bezier curve C(t) and D(t), we can write their first and second derivatives at t=0 and t=1 as

C'(1)=3(c3-c2)
C"(1)=6(c1-2c2+c3)
D'(0)=3(d1-d0)
D"(0)=6(d0-2d1+d2)

where d0 = c3.

For first and second derivative continuity at c3, we have C'(1)=D'(0) and C"(1)=D"(0), so

d1 = c3-c2+d0 = 2c3-c2 
d2 = c1-2c2+c3-d0+2d1 = c1+4(c3-c2).